# Typed.JS clear complete phrase and start new phrase with the typed feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using typed.js:

https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Everything looks good but there is an issue.

I am adding 4 phrases to be typed, and each phrase starts with the first two words being similar. Now typed.js keeps those  first two words and replaces the others with the new phrase.

I want these first two words to be retyped as well.

I have made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/t2ey5nqk/

```
<span class="type-wrapper">
    <span id="typed"></span>
</span>

$(function() {
    var typed = new Typed("#typed", {
        strings: [
            'When you smile at your phone',
            'When you read your book intently',
            'When you wake up in the morning',
            'When you go for a walk',
        ],
        typeSpeed: 50,
        backSpeed: 0,
        backDelay: 1000,
        startDelay: 1000,
        shuffle: false,
        loop: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay one solution I found to this was to add an empty phrase after each phrase ' '. This will clear the string before starting the second one. Maybe there is another way to do this through the plugin, but for now I shall be using this. I am keeping this question in case anyone else faces a similar issue and stumbles upon this :)

```
strings: [
    'When you smile at your phone',
    ' ',
    'When you read your book intently',
    ' ',
    'When you wake up in the morning',
    ' ',
    'When you go for a walk',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a tad bit late, but there is actually an option to do this.

```
smartBackSpace: false
```

If you see this, I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this option in the documentation?